# Queries not generated from migration

Tags: sqldelight

I am using sqldelight 1.4.1 on Android.

If I want to add tables in the second iteration of my app, where do I put the `CREATE TABLE Preset(blabla)` code?
If I put it in 1.sqm, no queries are generated, only `fun migrate(...)` code is generated. There is no code generated for `Preset` class nor for queries querying that specific database.

I can't add it in Preset.sq, because it crashes during runtime when I query Presets, since the table did not exist when the app first was run (because the first version did not have it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it needs to be in both, the `.sqm` file describe how to migrate, the `.sq` files describe how to create a fresh database, so in your case you'll need to add it to both in order to query from it in `.sq` files